# which IP Helper API interface to use?

Tags: c, windows, networking, network-programming, msdn

•Managing Network Adapters Using GetAdaptersInfo

•Managing Interfaces Using GetInterfaceInfo

•Managing IP Addresses Using GetIpAddrTable

These are the three methods listed on the msdn IP Helper API. Why would I prefer one method over another?

Comment: Im trying to A. get as much information about the state of the networking adapters (to diagnose a problem) and then B. be able to fix the problem (via changing a DNS server, gateway, static ip, dhcp server, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are mainly resulted from terminology differences, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for the explanation regarding "adapter" and "interface".  In short, an adapter is a data-link level abstraction while an interface being IP-level abstraction.

It will depend on the situation that you want to solve to determine what API to use.  For example, link speed or tunnel type can only be acquired from adapters.